# Does POSIX specify a memory consistency model (Addressing multithreading)?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, memory-model

Does POSIX specify a memory consistency model for its multithreading interface (semaphores and pthreads)? I'm not talking about atomic primitives, but a pseudo-formal specification for the visibility of side effects in the sense that C11 specifies *happens before*, *synchronize with*, *inter-thread happens before*, *modification-order*, *visible side effect* and so on (note that C11 uses these concepts not only for atomic primitives, but also for lock-based primitives such as `mtx_lock`/`mtx_unlock` and others that have an equivalent in POSIX).

Comment: POSIX is memory model agnostic.  POSIX calls are expected to behave correctly with respect to each other regardless of the memory model.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772656/memory-model-spec-in-pthreads

Comment: Note that POSIX 2008 of necessity refers to C99 rather than C11, so it doesn't have the verbiage associated with C11.